# minimizing eigenvalue of a product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

Which solver should be used in MATLAB for the following optimization problem:
Generating a non symmetric positive matrix B such that the product of B with a non symmetric positive matrix A has the minimum second largest eigenvalue. Both A and B are stochastic so largest eigenvalue is 1. I want to generate B such that

```
      minimize(second_largest_eigenvalue(B*A)), where A is known.
```

Note: cvx can only do this for symmetric matrices.

Comment: Can you write down a *complete* statement of your problem? You first talk about positive matrices (square, or rectangular?) with no other constraints but then in an aside you mention “oh by the way $A$ is stochastic and I need a constraint that $B$ is as well.”

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. What I want to say is that I have a known square stochastic matrix A and I want to find a square stochastic matrix B such that the second largest eigenvalue of product AB is minimized. The largest eigenvalue of AB will be 1 because product of stochastic matrices is also stochastic. Since my matrices are not symmetric I cannot use cvx for it.